# Delaying Mail with ActiveJobs won Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, rails-activejob

Looking at `ActiveJob` to delay mailer tasks (using delayed_jobs, delayed_jobs_active_record) and I have 2 questions about:

- ActiveJob's ActionMailer's `deliver_later` method
- If a job can have multiple perform methods

I have a `Post` model that requires email sent to moderators if it's updated and deleted.

```
# Post Model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
# Table name: posts
#
#  id         :integer
#  title      :string 
#  body       :text           
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime

  before_save :email_mod_post_updated, :email_mod_post_deleted

  private

    def email_mod_post_updated
      ModeratorMailerJob.updated_post_email(self).deliver_later
    end

    def email_mod_post_deleted
      ModeratorMailerJob.deleted_post_email(self).deliver_later
    end
end

# ModeratorMailer
class ModeratorMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "Mod <mod@domain.com>"

  def updated_post_email(post)
    @post = post
    mail(to: "mod@domain.com", subject: "Post Updated - #{@post.title}")
  end

  def deleted_post_email(post)
    @post = post
    mail(to: "mod@domain.com", subject: "Post Deleted - #{@post.title}")
  end
end
```

Current `ActiveJob` setup:

```
# app/jobs/updated_post_email_job.rb
class UpdatedPostEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(post)
    ModeratorMailer.updated_post_email(post)
  end
end

# app/jobs/deleted_post_email_job.rb
class DeletedPostEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(post)
    ModeratorMailer.deleted_post_email(post)
  end
end
```

**Question 1:**
With the `deliver_later` method, does this still relay on setting up an `ActiveJob` eg. `app/jobs/updated_post_email_job.rb` or is this not required (I have `delayed_job` running in the background)?

Would this be the same as calling `ModeratorMailerJob.perform_later(post)`

**Question 2:**
Do people add multiple perform methods in their active jobs eg:

```
class EmailModeratorJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(post)
    ModeratorMailer.updated_post(post)
  end


  def perform(post)
    ModeratorMailer.deleted_post(post)
  end
end
```

or is it best to have seperate jobs for a particular task?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveJob and mailers :

1. Setup ActiveJob with the adapter that suits your need.
2. Define your mailer with the different methods (1 by different kind of mail you send)
3. Use `deliver_later` method on your mailer. It will send your mail, in an asynchronous job, via the configured adapter.
4. That's all !

You don't have to define 1 job per mail, it's useless.

To answer your questions :

1. Already answered above
2. You should not have several methods with the same name in the same class
   : Each job should have **one** `perform` method that does the job.